# How long do zebra fishes remain transparent?

Tags: development, embryology

As larva, zebra fishes are transparent, at least up to 5-6 days. I wonder what would be the upper limit of the transparent period. This is of relevance considering purposes for imaging.

The question primarily relates to normal zebra fish, and not especially to transgenic breeds.

Comment: I slightly re-worded your question for clarity. Feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 3):

The upper limit of transparency time of zebrafishes is anywhere from two to three weeks for normal zebrafish for optimal high-resolution imaging. However, there is a modified species of Zebrafish called 'Casper' which is now the preferred zebrafish strain for studies in cancer and other research, because the length of transparency lasts into adulthood.

Sources:

1. http://medicalphysicsweb.org/cws/article/research/51394
2. https://biology.mit.edu/people/lisa_steiner#research_summary
3. http://www.the-scientist.com/?articles.view/articleNo/34834/title/Models-of-Transparency/